Crypto.com Exchange API Create Order unauthorised
I am trying to use Crypto.com API and when I am calling private/create-order to buy an instrument I am getting 401 Http status code with 40101 code, which means
Unauthorised - Not authenticated, or key/signature incorrect
I tried calling private/user-balance and i can successfully get my balance so it can't be the IP.
The difference between two calls is that balance call is a get call and has no params; however, the create order call does have params and when I am building the signature which is required for all authenticated calls, the params are also part of the signature and I believe I am doing something wrong there.
I am following this documentation -> https://exchange-docs.crypto.com/exchange/v1/rest-ws/index.html#introduction
This is my code for building the signature
Sign the request using HMAC SHA256
def sign_request(method, params, request_id):
"""Generate the signature following the HMAC-SHA256 process."""

# Step 1: Sort the request parameters alphabetically
if params:
    param_str = ''.join([f'{key}{params[key]}' for key in sorted(params)])
else:
    param_str = ''

# Step 2: Concatenate method, request id, api_key, param_str, and nonce
nonce = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
signature_payload = method + request_id + API_KEY + param_str + nonce

# Step 3: Create the HMAC-SHA256 signature using the API_SECRET
signature = hmac.new(
    bytes(API_SECRET, 'utf-8'),
    bytes(signature_payload, 'utf-8'),
    hashlib.sha256
).hexdigest()  # Step 4: Output the signature as a hex string

return signature, nonce

and this is what I am sending in as params
Params
params = {
    'instrument_name': symbol,
    'side': side,  # 'buy' or 'sell'
    'type': 'MARKET',  # or 'LIMIT'
    'price': price,
    'quantity': quantity,
    'client_oid': client_oid  # Add client order ID
}


It was my IP which got changed and not getting allow listed but the error kept on saying invalid signature.
